# How do I remove PyDev debugger breakpoints from deleted files?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, breakpoints

Whenever I launch the debugger from PyDev it complaints about breakpoints on files that don't exists anymore:

```
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: (some file path).py (will have no effect)
```

There are about a dozen of these phantom breakpoints on files that no longer exist in my workspace. Is there a way to suppress these or will I forever be saddled with these messages for removing files without removing their breakpoints first?

Comment: A `Breakpoints` view should be available in Eclipse's `Debug` perspective. Do you see those breakpoints there?

Comment: Yep, they appear in the Debug perspective in the Breakpoints tab. I cleaned up all of them and now I no longer have these messages. If you want to answer the question, I will accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Debug` perspective should give you access to a `Breakpoints` view (you can see its title bar in some of the screenshots in [this tutorial](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html)).

This view should list all your breakpoints, even if they relate to deleted files, and allow you to disable or remove them.

Answer (score 2):

today I just encountered this problem and I figured out how to solved it.
Very simple, you just need to click Run -> Remove all breakpoints :)

Comment: This option is not currently available at the PyDev view. That's probably the reason the OP asked in the first place.

Comment: Still didn't deserve a downvote. It's much easier and quicker than clicking all the checkboxes in the `Breakpoints` view.